# Add Class in Anchor for CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, anchor

First of all, I searched this question here and found some answers but they're not for me. My code is little bit different.

This is my anchor structure;

```
<?php echo anchor($this->lang->switch_uri('tr')); ?>
```

I need to use this anchor in this menu structure;

```
<li><a class="nav-icon"><i><img src="<?php echo site_url('assets/panel/flags/tr.png'); ?>" width="16" /></i> Türkçe</a></li>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a class by creating a array in the anchor.

example

```
 <?=  anchor('your link here', 'Name of the anchor', array('title' => 'your anchor title', 'class'=>'your anchor class here')) ?>
```

Put this where you want a anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the URL helper;

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

```
echo anchor('news/local/123', 'My News', array('title' => 'The best news!'));
```

Would produce: `<a href="http://example.com/index.php/news/local/123" title="The best news!">My News</a>`

So, yours would be;

```
echo '<li>' . anchor('#', '<img src="img_path" /> Text', array('class' => 'myClass')) . '</li>';
```

Comment: thank you but i already know that, my problem is this part; `$this->lang->switch_uri('tr')`

Comment: Ah sorry - I don't think I have ever used the switch_uri function. Cannot find it in the user_guide either.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It should be like this;

```
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url($this->lang->switch_uri('tr')); ?>" class="nav-icon"><i><img src="<?php echo site_url('assets/panel/flags/tr.png'); ?>" width="16" /></i> Türkçe</a></li>
```